# I changed an occurrence for a recurring meeting however when the usual time came up for that meeting it still notified me

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, meetings

I created a reoccurring meeting, but needed to change one singular occurrence to a different time/day of the week. I did this with no issue. However, when the time came for when the meeting is usually scheduled, I still got the 15 minute notification. I knew this was incorrect, but other people in my meeting got this notification too and were confused. Is this an issue when someone does not "accept" the new time for the single occurrence? Or is there something else going on?

Comment: Based on my test, when i updated the time of singular occurrence, the reminder didn't prompt as the old time coming, how did you update the singular occurrence? And does this issue occur in web mail or Outlook desktop client?

Comment: I am writing to see how everything is going on with this thread. Should you need more help on this, you can feel free to post back.